# How can I save a filename with UTC time in vim?

Tags: vim, utc

I am trying to save a file name that includes the date and time.  However, I would like the date and time to be in UTC.  This is what I am doing:

In vimrc:

```
cmap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")<CR>
```

I type this when I save the file:

```
:w i<F3>.txt
```

and I get a file that is named:

```
i[localtime].txt
```

but I want:

```
i[UTCtime].txt
```

Is there a way to actually do this, or am I stuck with my local time forever?  Vim is my only way to explore various time zones, please help me. :)

Oh and by the way, I will be using both Linux and Windows for this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure whether this will work correctly on Linux or not, but I believe so (I'm on a Mac).

The idea, is that you can use the `date` utility to retrieve the time with more flexibility. It accepts an option `-u` which outputs the time in UTC. All you have to to is wrap that in a `system()` call.

```
cmap <F3> <C-R>=system('date -u "+%Y%m%d%H%M"')<CR>
```

And there you have your formatted UTC time.

If a null character appears at the end of the time inserted (it appears as `^@`) then you may want to append a `[:-2]` to strip it from the returning string, right before the `<CR>` in the mapping above. That comes from the translated newline the system outputs. Check `:h NL-used-for-Nul`.

About windows, well I have no clue. You may want to try out the utility in Linux before mapping things, but I'm almost sure there will be no differences.

Comment: Windows does not return time in UTC.  Linux will work fine though.